# Partial derivatives definition - invariance to change of the basis

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm trying to understand the definition of partial derivatives. I will give a brief introduction to how my math book defines it.
We consider a function $f: E \to R$ where $E \subset R^n$ and a limit point $x \in E$. We say that function $f$ is differentiable at $x$ if:
$$f(x + h) - f(x) = L(x)(h) + \alpha(x; h)$$ where $L(x): R^n \to R$ is a linear function of $h$, $\alpha(x; h)=o(h)$ having $h \to 0, x + h \in E$.
We can write it using coordinates of the vectors:
$$f(x^1 + h^1, ..., x^n + h^n) - f(x^1, ..., x^n) = a_1(x)h^1 + ... + a_n(x)h^n + o(h)$$
Numbers $a_1(x), ..., a_n(x)$ are partial derivatives.
To find $a_i(x)$ we consider $h_i = 0 \cdot e_1 + ... + h^ie_i + ... + 0 \cdot e_n$ for some basis ${e_1, ..., e_n}$. Then $a_i(x) = \lim_{h^i \to 0}\frac{f(x^1, ..., x^i + h^i,..., x^n ) - f(x^1, ..., x^i, ..., x^n)}{h^i} =: \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}$
I'm concerned by involving a basis into the definition and using coordinates with respect to it. The question is whether this partial derivative is invariant to change of the basis.
It seems to me that partial derivatives are coordinates of a covector, so they are subject to change when changing the basis. But if we look in the definition of a derivative for some function $f: R \to R$ then we won't find any covectors but just scalars, so the derivative is just a scalar that is independent of any basis. This is the fact that confuses me.

Answer (score 1):

The   derivative itself is the linear function $L$. It is independent of any choice of basis - you can see that in the definition of "differentiable".

When you choose a basis, you can calculate the components of $L$.   Those are the partial derivatives corresponding to that basis.

I recommend that you work out a simple example in the plane - perhaps $f(x,y) = x^2 + 2y^2$ for the usual basis and the basis $\{(1,-1), (1,  1)\}$.